# Typescript intellisense to pick up exports only from root index file

Tags: typescript

I have a local package where my files are structured like this:

```
.
├── a[folder]
│   ├── file1.ts
│   │       export function a() {}
│   └── index.ts
│           export * from "./file1";
│
├── b[folder]
│   ├── file2.ts
│   │       export function b() {}
│   └── index.ts
│           export * from "./file2";
│
├── c[folder]
│   ├── file3.ts
│   │       export function c() {}
│   └── index.ts
│           export * from "./file3";
│
└── index.ts
        export * from "./a[folder]";
        export * from "./b[folder]";
        export * from "./c[folder]";
```

Now, when importing for example `function a` to my project intellisense picks up all exports:

- from index.ts
- from a[folder]
- from a[folder]/file1.ts

Can I make it work like that only the **root** index.ts exports are shown?